# Optimising Python script for scraping to avoid getting blocked/ draining resources

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scripting, sleep

I have a fairly basic Python script that scrapes a property website, and stores the address and price in a csv file. There are over 5000 listings to go through but I find my current code times out after a while (about 2000 listings) and the console shows 302 and CORS policy errors.

```
import requests
import itertools
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer
from random import randint
from time import sleep
from datetime import date


url = "https://www.propertypal.com/property-for-sale/northern-ireland/page-"
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
filename = date.today().strftime("ni-listings-%Y-%m-%d.csv")

with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = writer(f)
    header = ['Address', 'Price']
    thewriter.writerow(header)

    # for page in range(1, 3):
    for page in itertools.count(1):
        req = requests.get(f"{url}{page}", headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

        for li in soup.find_all('li', class_="pp-property-box"):
            title = li.find('h2').text
            price = li.find('p', class_="pp-property-price").text

            info = [title, price]
            thewriter.writerow(info)

        sleep(randint(1, 5))

# this script scrapes all pages and records all listings and their prices in daily csv
```

As you can see I added `sleep(randint(1, 5))` to add random intervals but I possibly need to do more. Of course I want to scrape the page in its entirety as quickly as possible but I also want to be respectful to the site that is being scraped and minimise burdening them.

Can anyone suggest updates? Ps forgive rookie errors, very new to Python/scraping!

Comment: I have updated the OP code snippet with the suggested update from an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of getting that data - bear in mind there are 251 pages only, with 12 properties on each of them, not **over 5k**:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin'
}
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
big_list = []
for x in tqdm(range(1, 252)):
    soup = bs(s.get(f'https://www.propertypal.com/property-for-sale/northern-ireland/page-{x}').text, 'html.parser')
#     print(soup)
    properties = soup.select('li.pp-property-box')
    for p in properties:
        name = p.select_one('h2').get_text(strip=True) if p.select_one('h2') else None
        url = 'https://www.propertypal.com' + p.select_one('a').get('href') if p.select_one('a') else None
        price = p.select_one('p.pp-property-price').get_text(strip=True) if p.select_one('p.pp-property-price') else None
        big_list.append((name, price, url))
big_df = pd.DataFrame(big_list, columns = ['Property', 'Price', 'Url'])
print(big_df)
```

Result printed in terminal:

```
100%
251/251 [03:41<00:00, 1.38it/s]
Property    Price   Url
0   22 Erinvale Gardens, Belfast, BT10 0FS  Asking price£165,000    https://www.propertypal.com/22-erinvale-gardens-belfast/777820
1   Laurel Hill, 37 Station Road, Saintfield, BT24 7DZ  Guide price£725,000 https://www.propertypal.com/laurel-hill-37-station-road-saintfield/751274
2   19 Carrick Brae, Burren Warrenpoint, Newry, BT34 3TH    Guide price£265,000 https://www.propertypal.com/19-carrick-brae-burren-warrenpoint-newry/775302
3   7b Conway Street, Lisburn, BT27 4AD Offers around£299,950   https://www.propertypal.com/7b-conway-street-lisburn/779833
4   Hartley Hall, Greenisland   From£280,000to£397,500  https://www.propertypal.com/hartley-hall-greenisland/d850
... ... ... ...
3007    8 Shimna Close, Newtownards, BT23 4PE   Offers around£99,950    https://www.propertypal.com/8-shimna-close-newtownards/756825
3008    7 Barronstown Road, Dromore, BT25 1NT   Guide price£380,000 https://www.propertypal.com/7-barronstown-road-dromore/756539
3009    39 Tamlough Road, Randalstown, BT41 3DP Offers around£425,000   https://www.propertypal.com/39-tamlough-road-randalstown/753299
3010    Glengeen House, 17 Carnalea Road, Fintona, BT78 2BY Offers over£180,000 https://www.propertypal.com/glengeen-house-17-carnalea-road-fintona/750105
3011    Walnut Road, Larne, BT40 2WE    Offers around£169,950   https://www.propertypal.com/walnut-road-larne/749733
3012 rows × 3 columns
```

See relevant documentation for Requests: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

For Pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/

For BeautifulSoup: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

And for TQDM: https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/

Comment: thanks Barry - that's really helpful. I've actually updated the OP with your snippet. I've updated things a little, as I only really care about the address & price. I'm struggling to understand why when I change the urls (to one that has a lot less pages) it still is going through all 251. Also - I struggled to add it all to a CSV file, any more feedback would be really appreciated!

Comment: To save the pandas dataframe to csv you just to `df.to_csv('ni_housing_stuff.csv')`. Also, I'm not sure why you copied my code in your question, considering my code solves your question. @cts

Comment: Thanks Barry - sorry bad idea on putting your code in the OP, rolled back now!